# C error - wait()

Tags: c, wait

I write a program using memory segments but the problem is my wait() is throwing me an error

error:

```
ks.c:24:2: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘wait’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/wait.h:116:16: note: expected ‘__WAIT_STATUS’ but argument is of type ‘int’
s.c:13:6: warning: unused variable ‘w’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Code line is simple `wait(1);`  and i have includeted  all neccesarry ehaders for the project why do i get that error, since it should work like this...
imports

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "st.h"
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the definition of `wait`.

Comment: Stupid question, but you didn't mean `sleep`, did you?

Comment: no, and my teacher uses wait(1) or (10) all the time

Comment: @Mr Lister At least the error message the OP pasted says `incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘wait’` :))

Comment: @user1388172 could you be wrong and mean `exit(1)` or `exit(10)` indeed? ...for what your teacher uses, not the above code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation for `wait`, what it takes as parameter is a *pointer to int* where to set the status. Since this is homework, I'll let you conclude the solution yourself.

Comment: I'm using in this maner wait() because my teacher showed  during lectures soem examples and they worked... that is why i'm curious why does it not work for me

Comment: @user1388172: You should ask your teacher for clarifications on why his code works...

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the manual page for [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) it requires a pointer to an integer.

So your code should read something like

```
int status;
wait(&status);
```

Comment: We have such creative examples :)

Answer (score 0):

The wait function actually take a pointer to an int and returns the exit status of the thread's child in that pointer.

Try something like this

```
 int status;
 wait(&status);
```

Comment: I'm using in this maner wait() because my teacher showed  during lectures soem examples and they worked... that is why i'm curious why does it not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message thoroughly. It says `incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘wait’` and then `note: expected ‘__WAIT_STATUS’ but argument is of type ‘int’`. You can then have a look in the manual `$ man wait` where everything's very shortly explained - argument and return types, typical values, etc. You might even get lucky and find an example without even searching the net.
If you were missing a `.h`eader file, you would have gotten a different error message